# How can I capture a photo through a microscope using a D5200 with lens

Tags: nikon, macro, microscopy

Which is the best mode to take a photo through a microscope, using a Nikon d5200 through a lens

Comment: More information needed. Are you using an adaptor to mount the camera on the microscope? Are you attempting to shoot through a camera lens through the eyepiece of said microscope? Help us help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a fairly simple way of taking a photo through a microscope?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16476/whats-a-fairly-simple-way-of-taking-a-photo-through-a-microscope)

Comment: I am attempting to shoot through a camera lens through the eyepiece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hand-hold the camera to the eyepiece of the microscope. Best to mount a UV filter atop the camera lens, such a filter will serve to prevent scratches.

When the microscope (same for telescope) is focused for your eyes, the light rays emerge from the instruments eyepiece as parallel rays. These rays are said to be "afocal" meaning they do not converge or diverge to a focus. The afocal position allows you to abut your camera to the eyepiece. You can make an adapter using PVC pipe or you can purchase afocal adapters.

Check out this link for ideas.

https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=afocal+adapter

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be a [t-mound adpater](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=t-mount%20adapter%20microsope%20eye%20piece&rh=n%3A172282%2Ck%3At-mount%20adapter%20microsope%20eye%20piece). You can try to hand hold it but because of the aperture difference of the microscope versus your DX lenses this will be almost useless.  (You may have good luck with a cellphone or a pinhole lens for your Nikon.)

Answer (score 0):

Definately dont hand hold.  If your microscope has an eyepiece that can be taken out,  you can use a barlow lens. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=microscope+dslr&espv=2&biw=1097&bih=552&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAmoVChMI5ufWzeiSyAIVRqgeCh0YpA77
check that out.

Go to B&H photo and video's website,  and you can chat with them about how toget one.

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/find/liveChat.jsp

Comment: `Definitely don't hand hold` : why ? Can you explain why a Barlow lens is a better solution ? (Wikipedia link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barlow_lens)